# Check integer value is greater then 0 in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5.1, laravel-5

I am writing the below code to make sure that the integer value is greater then 0

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'DUIHistoryID'          => 'required|integer|between:1,11',
    ];
}
```

Am I missing something? validation is not working in the above code

Comment: You want to check an integer value, but I see no integer validation in the code above. Where is the var you're checking? if (is_numeric($var) && $var > 0) will work for your condition in the title.

Comment: This is Laravel. I am using `rules()` method inside `Request` class.

Comment: not working means what? exception, or anything passes validation? are you injecting the correct request class in your controller action? does it pass validation even if you don't include 'DUIHistoryID'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

need to add below function in the request class.

```
public function messages() {
    return [
        'DUIHistoryID.min' => 'Please select DUI History',
    ];
}
```